# Read Anylogic schedule exceptions from database table

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

How can I read a list of exception dates for a schedule from an Excel file without having to adopt each date from the file separately? I am trying to set up a shift-plan which takes into account holidays, etc. over the next 5 years. For this I have created an Excel table containing a list of holiday dates, which I would now like to use in my AnyLogic simulation. I tried the exceptions section of my schedule object, but didn't find a way to connect this section to my excel file. The only option I am getting here is to manually enter each date... Since this would be extremely tedious, I am looking for a workaround (Java Code?). Can someone help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a scheduled object of type integer and a database table full of exception dates that you want the integer value of the schedule to be 0 for the entire day.

You can then programmatically add exceptions to your scheduling with the following code

```
List<Tuple> rows = selectFrom(db_table).list();

for (Tuple row : rows) {
    Date exceptionDate = row.get( db_table.db_column );
    schedule.addException(exceptionDate.getYear(), exceptionDate.getMonth(), exceptionDate.getDay(), exceptionDate.getHours(), exceptionDate.getMinutes(), exceptionDate.getSeconds(), 
                        exceptionDate.getYear(), exceptionDate.getMonth(), exceptionDate.getDay()+1, exceptionDate.getHours(), exceptionDate.getMinutes(), exceptionDate.getSeconds(),
0, false);
}
```

The format for adding exceptions is a bit cumbersome but it is:

```
schedule.addException(startYear, startMonth, startDay, startHour, startMinute, startSecond, endYear, endMonth, endDay, endHour, endMinute, endSecond, value, annually);
```

The `value` object is the value of your schedule type

Comment: Thank you! -Where would you say is the best place to insert the code? Under the schedule properties in the "Action" field?

Comment: A separate function that you run on start of model. 
Remember to make sure that all data from the database is only accessed from the model once, best read it all in at the start of the model and then store it in some form and then use it from there. 
If you found my answer helpful remember to upvote and accept it ;-)

Comment: Thanks again -JFYI: I already tried upvoting your answer, but it seems I don't have enough 'reputation' points yet to do that... sorry!

Answer (score 0):

True, there is no build-in way for this. You need to code your schedule. This allows adding exceptions programmatically, see https://anylogic.help/anylogic/data/schedule.html#creating-and-initializing-schedule-from-code-on-model-startup

Specifically:
[image]

Comment: @emw glad it was. Please upvote useful answers so other can benefit as well, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote